# add node to rst doctree and save to file

Tags: python, docutils

**I'd like to insert a custom node into a doctree and save these changes to file.**

I'm reading the following RST file...

```
Hello World!
############

:date: 2010-10-03 10:20
:author: James Bond

This is a test.
```

like this:

```
doctree = docutils.core.publish_doctree(open('test.rst').read())
```

I'd now like to insert a new node :id: 234123 to the docinfo and save it as test.rst. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reStructuredText writer.

See the answer here: [Is there a reST Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804333/is-there-a-rest-writer/13805167#13805167)

if it's a trivial change you're better off writing a simple function that reads the file as lines of text, which it writes out to a new text file, inserting the new line at some point during parsing/writing.