# Resolve Substitutions in RestructuredText

Tags: python, substitution, restructuredtext, docutils

I want to take the following restructured text snippet that contains a [substitution definition](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions):

```
text = """

|python|

.. |python| image:: python.jpg
"""
```

And resolve the definitions so the substitution text is displayed:

```
resolved_text = """
.. image:: python.jpg

"""
```

Is there a function or utility in docutils or another module that can do this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Is there a reST Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804333/is-there-a-rest-writer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docutils` provides [publisher functions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html#publisher-convenience-functions) to use docutils as a library.

So using `docutils.core.publish_string` could be an option for your usecase.

```
In [90]: from docutils import core

In [91]: text = '|python|\n\n.. |python| image:: python.jpg\n'

In [92]: print core.publish_string(text)
<document source="<string>">
    <paragraph>
        <image alt="python" uri="python.jpg">
    <substitution_definition names="python">
        <image alt="python" uri="python.jpg">
```

By default `puplish_string` uses a `pseudoxml` writer, which you can see in the output.
However if you really want to have the plain text output from your question, you need a custom writer class derived from `docutils.writers.Writer`.
I'm not sure how to implement this, maybe the `Sphinx` [TextWriter](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/8ec0b3a74e791e59dfee2d484380c34881530a89/sphinx/writers/text.py?at=default#cl-133) could be a starting point.

Seems that if you really only need the simple substitution, using `replace` on your text would be a simpler solution, if you need more complicated things, implement this using docutils is complicated, too.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like this is the only approach to take, I was hoping there would be something already available, but it appears not.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Docutils Hacker's Guide](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html). It explains how docutils works.

You might get away with applying an appropriate `Transform` to the node tree that is generated by parsing the input file. After applying the transform you should use a `Writer` object to output ReStructuredText again. This writer doesn't exist yet, so you'd have to create that first.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. bmu expanded slightly further on this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I fully understand the question, but here is a stab at the extraction using list comprehension:

```
extracted_line = [x for x in text.split("\n") if x[:2] == ".."][0]
resolved_text = """{}""".format(extracted_line.replace("|python|",""))
```

You'll need to add some logic if more than one occurrence of the sub def is expected.

Comment: Thanks - this is fine solution for a few replacements, but I was hoping for a robust solution that would work on any rst