# Write reStructuredText t programmatically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docutils

Is there any Python3.X library that helps to write rST file/text.
I do not want to write rST file with manual styling with file.write(). I am looking for a library which makes it easier to create an rST file with different elements like bold, underline, tables.

**Note**: I do not want to read a rST file, rather I want to create a rST file programmatically

Comment: Look into Pandoc, docutils, sphinx

Comment: I do look into sphinx but as far as I found it is only parsing a rST file.

Comment: Where is this library you are looking for suppose to get its content from? Normally a Human writes RST and then a computer will turn that into a final product (HTML, PDF, etc...)

Comment: I wished to have a have library which makes my life easier to create and write rST file. e.g. subsubtitle text, writing it with file.write(subsubtitle) and  file.write(*********) I find it too cumbersome.

Comment: I was wondering something similar to get around some other problem. At one point I considered hacking up rst2rst. I found a more standard solution - so this was not necessary for me. rst2rst: https://pypi.org/project/rst2rst/

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Is there a reST Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804333/is-there-a-rest-writer)

Answer (score 2):

Use [RstCloth](https://github.com/thclark/rstcloth) to create RST-files via an easy Python API.

```
from rstcloth import RstCloth

d = RstCloth()
d.title('Example Use')
d.newline()
d.h2('Contents')
d.directive(name="contents", fields=[('local', ''), ('backlinks', 'None')])
d.newline()
d.h2('Code -- shebang')
d.codeblock('#!/usr/bin/env')

d.print_content()
```

Result:

```
===========
Example Use
===========

Contents
--------

.. contents::
   :local:
   :backlinks: None

Code -- shebang
---------------

::

   #!/usr/bin/env
```